# translate CSRA from pyTorch to TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I'm trying to implement the CSRA module from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.02456v2.pdf) in TensorFlow instead of PyTorch, using MobileNetV3 as a feature extractor.

I'm only versed in TensorFlow, and I'm running into some trouble translating from PyTorch to TensorFlow.

The [official source code](https://github.com/Kevinz-code/CSRA/blob/master/pipeline/csra.py) implementing the module uses some functions that are not commonly used in TensorFlow, and the tf docs for those functions offer little help.

The source code is the following:

```
class CSRA(nn.Module): # one basic block 
    def __init__(self, input_dim, num_classes, T, lam):
        super(CSRA, self).__init__()
        self.T = T      # temperature       
        self.lam = lam  # Lambda                        
        self.head = nn.Conv2d(input_dim, num_classes, 1, bias=False)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=2)

    def forward(self, x):
        # x (B d H W)
        # normalize classifier
        # score (B C HxW)
        score = self.head(x) / torch.norm(self.head.weight, dim=1, keepdim=True).transpose(0,1)
        score = score.flatten(2)
        base_logit = torch.mean(score, dim=2)

        if self.T == 99: # max-pooling
            att_logit = torch.max(score, dim=2)[0]
        else:
            score_soft = self.softmax(score * self.T)
            att_logit = torch.sum(score * score_soft, dim=2)

        return base_logit + self.lam * att_logit

     score_soft = self.softmax(score * self.T)
     att_logit = torch.sum(score * score_soft, dim=2)

 return base_logit + self.lam * att_logit
```

I don't need to define CSRA as a class, I'm trying to stitch the module together as a keras functional model. This is the code I've managed to put together:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 3))

head = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, kernel_size=1, padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(None, None, None, 960))

features = base_model(inputs, training=False)

print(head.get_weights())

score = head(features) / tf.transpose((tf.linalg.normalize(head.get_weights(), axis=3)), perm=(0,1))

shape = scores.get_shape().as_list()

score = tf.reshape(score, [-1, shape[1] * shape[2], shape[3]])

# scores = tf.reshape(scores[1:2])

avg_scores = tf.keras.backend.mean(score, axis=1)
max_scores_act = tf.keras.activations.softmax(score, axis=1)
max_scores = tf.math.reduce_sum(max_scores_act * score, axis=1)
outputs = (avg_scores + max_scores*0.2)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

The major problem I'm having is the step to obtain a `score` in TensorFlow. The current problem I'm facing seems to be that the object returned by `head.get_weights()` is an empty list. I understand that because `head` is 'empty', its weights are zeroes, but how to define `score` then?

Besides this, I have many doubts regarding the translation. Since pyTorch works with "channels first" and TensorFlow with "channels last", I had to change the dims that are affected in each step, but I don't know if I'm doing it right and if all operations in PyTorch are necessary for TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some digging of the pythorch docs, I mostly figured it out

What was throwing me off is that instead of using pre-made layers, the code is implementing the layers from grounds up

Regarding the access to the FC layer weights, there's a fundamental difference between pytorch's `weight` attribute and tensorflow's get_weights() method. The former returns the weights of the layer's output, while the latter returns the weights of the layer. Anyways, this step was necessary for weight normalization, which is conveniently implmented in tensorflow